# How to get substrings in a comma separated string?

Tags: regex, string, csv

I am trying to design some regex pattern to get substring in a comma separated string. I only know the number of commas up to that substring.

This is the log:

```
str1,2019/05/22 
15:29:09,012001028720,THREAT,vulnerability,1,2019/05/22 
15:29:09,IP1,IP2,0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0,some info here,,,ftp,
```

And this is the regex i've tried:

```
.*vulnerability[,]{1}(.*)
```

This is the result with my regex:

```
1,2019/05/22 15:29:09,IP1,IP2,0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0,some info here,,,ftp,
```

Obviously, the regex is completely wrong since I don't know how to iterate over commas. How can I jump 11 commas and get the ftp substring?

Comment: In which flavor are you working? Python? Also, what do you mean by jumping 11 commas? Which is the exact output you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat matching not a comma followed by a comma `[^,\n]*,`

In the first example you could repeat that `{8}` times, for the second example `{9}` times using a quantifier and capture your value in a capturing group.

```
^(?:[^,\n]*,){9}([^,\n]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wSfejq/1)